# Matching column with row according to data from array

Tags: php

I have two set off array, in one I hold colors in another dimensions. Those array I use to make queries and later print result in table.

```
$colors = array(
"27" => "RAL 9002", 
"255" => "RAL 9006", 
"341" => "RAL 8019", 
"286" => "RAL 7016", 
"141" => "RAL 3009",
"171" => "RAL 6028", 
"121" => "RAL 8004", 
"221" => "RAL 5010",
"101" => "RAL 3000", 
"273" => "RAL 9007"); 

$dimensions =  array
  (
  array(0.3,1245),
  array(0.35,1245),
  array(0.40,1100),
  array(0.45,1245),
  array(0.50,1245),
  array(0.60,1245),
  array(0.70,1245) 
  );
```

According to the values above I make query:

```
foreach($colors as $key => $value)
    {

foreach($dimensions as $data )
    { 
        $sql = "SELECT sum(Kolicina) as suma 
        FROM materijali WHERE Debljina = $data[0] AND Sirina = $data[1] AND Boja = $key";

        $q = $conn->query($sql);

        while($r=$q->fetch()) {

            $debljina = $data[0];
            $sirina = $data[1];
            $kolicina = $r["suma"];
            $kod = $key;

            if(empty($kolicina)) {
                $kolicina = '0.00';
            }

            $vrijednosti[] = $debljina.'x'.$sirina.'--'.$kod;
        }

    }
}
```

Result I receive from above I should print in table. For some reason I dont get good result, It always displays red. Not sure if I should use isset() function.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead> 
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo "Dimenzije"; ?> </th>
                <?php foreach($colors as $boja) { ?>            
                <th><?php echo $boja; ?> </th> 
                <?php  } ?>
            </tr> 
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
        <?php foreach($dimensions as $dim) {  
           ?>
            <tr>  
                <td><?php  
                echo $dim[0] . ' X ' . $dim[1]; ?>  </td>  
                <?php
                    foreach($colors as $key => $value) {    
                        // if ($vrijednosti[$dim[0].'--'.$dim[1].'--'.$key]) {  
                        if (isset($vrijednosti[$dim[0].'x'.$dim[1] .'--'.$key])) {  

                            echo '<td style="background:blue"> </td>';  
                        }  

                        else {

                            echo '<td style="background:red">' .$vrijednosti[$dim[0].'x'.$dim[1] .'-'.$key] .' </td>'; 

                        }

                    }
                ?>  </td> 
            </tr>
            <?php } 

        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

When I dump array $vrijednosti I get following format (I just took 5elements)

```
array(70) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "0.3x1245--27"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "0.35x1245--27"
  [2]=>
  string(12) "0.4x1100--27"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "0.45x1245--27"
  [4]=>
  string(12) "0.5x1245--27"
```

Table does not show good results, dont have idea what could be wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Table looks like this. Table forms looks well. In cells it should display $kolicina which I get in while loop.

[image]

Comment: Your dump is `string(12) "0.3x1245--27"` and you look for `if (isset($vrijednosti[$dim[0].'x'.$dim[1] .'-'.$key])) `. First has two dashes, second only one.

Comment: I have fixed, but I got the same error. Nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

```
$vrijednosti[] = $debljina.'x'.$sirina.'--'.$kod;
```

creates a numeric indexed array. But your `if` checks for the presence of an array key in $vrijednosti:

```
if (isset($vrijednosti[$dim[0].'x'.$dim[1] .'--'.$key])) { ... }
```

Thats always false. You have to check for an element, not a key:

```
if (in_array($dim[0].'x'.$dim[1] .'--'.$key, $vrijednosti) { ... }
```

Comment: Yes you are right: I just need to add $kolicina from while loop, I am having trouble it displays always 0 and it should not